# How to programmatically output fragmented mp4 file using libavformat?

Tags: mp4, libavformat

I want to use mp4 file format for live streaming, which is not possible with an unfragmented mp4 file, as the moov atom is generally written at the end of the file. I need to generate a fragmented mp4 file to transfer it over a network for live streaming. I am using libavformat. The problem is, I can write unfragmented mp4 files easily with libavformat, but I don't know how to write a fragmented mp4 file. So, how to write a fragmented mp4 file using libavformat?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are looking for fragmented mp4 (FYI a fragmented mp4 is usually called  .ismv) ISMV requires a media server and specialized client to stream.

I think what you are looking for is faststart. This simply moves the moov atom to the start of the file. ffmpeg comes with a qt-faststart utility that will do this for you. Check you distrobution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bento4 library to do this easily. Download from here http://www.bento4.com/downloads/ and use the binary mp4fragment.

mp4fragment sourcefile destinatiofile